# how to find average of numbers in a column if some cells in the column are blank?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Let's say, we have some numbers in B1:B9, but some cell in the range are empty. How to fine average of the numbers in cells that are not empty?

All my trials led to div/o error.

Comment: Please check COALESC function, it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The `average` function will ignore empty cells and text. Use this:

```
=AVERAGE(B1:B9)
```